# c++ template operator no match found

Tags: c++, templates

Ok, new question about c++ templates...

I'm writing a template class for 2d/3d/4d vectors ( as in geometric vectors, not arrays ).
All's well, after a bunch of questions here in SO, but now operators are not found, for some reason.
If i declare them inside the class, it's ok, but if i declare them externally AS A TEMPLATE, they're not found.
Funny enough, if i specifically declare them with the correct variable types, then all is well again. So it basically seems as though that function template is never instantiated.

So, the error is:

```
error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Math::TVector<int, 3ul>’ and ‘Math::TVector<int, 3ul>’)
```

even though there's a function for it:

```
template <typename Type, unsigned TemplateElementCount>
Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> operator - ( Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> &First, Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> &Second )
{
Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> Result;
for ( unsigned cont = 0; cont < TemplateElementCount; ++cont )
    Result.Data[cont] = First.Data[cont] - Second.Data[cont];
return Result;
}
```

An example of the code is available at http://goo.gl/qrZaU1
I've tried declaring it inside the namespace, outside it, outside it with full resolution ( including Math:: everywhere ) and nothing works..
Can anyone lend me a hand?
Thanks

EDIT:
Full compile error is

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':                                                                                  
main.cpp:16:23: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'Math::TVector<int, 3ul>' and 'Math::TVector<int, 3ul>')     
 Vector1 = Vector1 - Vector2;                                                                                               
                   ^                                                                                                        
main.cpp:16:23: note: candidate is:                                                                                             
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:                                                                                             
Point.h:171:43: note: template<class Type, unsigned int TemplateElementCount> Math::TVector<Type, TemplateElementCount> operator
-(Math::TVector<Type, TemplateElementCount>&, Math::TVector<Type, TemplateElementCount>&)                                       
 Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> operator - ( Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> &First, Math::TVector <Type,Te
mplateElementCount> &Second )                                                                                                   
                                       ^                                                                                    
Point.h:171:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:                                                        
main.cpp:16:25: note:   mismatched types 'unsigned int' and '#'integer_cst' not supported by dump_type#<type error>'            
 Vector1 = Vector1 - Vector2;                                                                                               
                     ^                                                                                                      
main.cpp:16:25: note:   'Math::TVector<int, 3ul>' is not derived from 'Math::TVector<Type, TemplateElementCount>'
```

Comment: I doubt that line from the error output is the only one, please edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error output. Also please show the code you use to call the function, including the declarations of the variables involved.

Comment: [it does compile](http://ideone.com/gaQy2K)

Comment: @Axalo Then it's even stranger. what's wrong with gcc to not like that code?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If you follow the link i provided in the question you can see the code along with the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (or at least, one of the problems) seems to be that you are using `unsigned` as the type of the second non-type template argument of `operator -`, while the class `TVector` is instantiated with a corresponding non-type template argument of type of `std::size_t`. The two types are not necessarily the same (according to the compiler error you are receiving, it seems `std::size_t` resolves to `unsigned long` on your platform), hence the error.

Changing the function's signature as follows should fix the problem:

```
template <typename Type, std::size_t TemplateElementCount>
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> operator - (
    Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> &First, 
    Math::TVector <Type,TemplateElementCount> &Second )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: very good idea, but it did not... still the same exact error.

Comment: @RhiakathFlanders: That's strange. After making that modification on the online code you linked, I was able to compile and execute. Is the code you linked the same that you are using?

Comment: @RhiakathFlanders: Also, are you sure the error you are getting is exactly the same for the exact same function call, rather than a call to another function that you haven't fixed yet?  [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57e5042789b43bd2) summarizes your problem.

Comment: Got it!  Since it's a header, for some reason cmake decided not to recompile it. I had to do a clean/build cycle, and now it's ok! That size_t thing was the issue. Thanks!